# Use custom method to define mapping for ModelMapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I would like to map some entity to another using org.modelmapper.ModelMapper. The problem is that in order to set some value to the target entity I need to calculate this value based on the value of source entity.

I produced such code:

```
private TargerEntity convertToTargerEntity( SourceEntity src ) {
    this.modelMapper.typeMap( SourceEntity.class, TargerEntity.class )
            .addMapping( src -> src.getUser().getId(), TargerEntity::setUserId )
            .addMapping( src -> getValueProperty(src), TargerEntity::setEvaluatedValue );

    return this.modelMapper.map( src, TargerEntity.class );
}
```

And the method that responsible for calculation looks like:

```
private String getValueProperty( SourceEntity entity ) {
    return entity.getInformation().stream()
        .filter( property -> Objects.equals( property.getName(), "desiredPropertyValue" ) )
        .findFirst().orElse( null );
}
```

But while mapping I get an org.modelmapper.internal.ErrorsException without any additional messages.

What can be a cause of such behavior? Should It works at all?

Comment: no, it will not work. If you provide me `Information` field structure I will help with mapping

Answer (score 4):

Try use `Converter`:

```
private TargerEntity convertToTargerEntity(SourceEntity src) {
    Converter<Information, String> converter =
            ctx -> ctx.getSource() == null ? "" : ctx.getSource().stream()
                    .filter(property -> Objects.equals(property.getName(), "desiredPropertyValue"))
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);

    this.modelMapper.typeMap(SourceEntity.class, TargerEntity.class 
            .addMapping(src -> src.getUser().getId(), TargerEntity::setUserId)
            .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(converter).map(SourceEntity::getInformation, TargerEntity::setEvaluatedValue));

    return this.modelMapper.map(src, TargerEntity.class);
}
```

Replace `Information` type with yours. Also converter can be defined as Singleton object.